# How do you return the 2nd through nth match of a vbscript regex capturing group

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a regular expression that matches a particular text string and then is supposed to return the matches in cells adjacent to the matched string. I'm using a capturing group so there could be more than one match. I'm able to return the first match without any problems, but I can't figure out how to return the second through nth matches.

My code follow:

```
Sub splitUpComments()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G5")

    For Each c In Myrange
        strPattern = "(\S.+?[.?!])(?=\s+|$)"
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = c.Value
            strReplace = "$1"

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                c.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
                c.Offset(0, 2) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
                c.Offset(0, 3) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$3")
            Else
                'do nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Given the following Target String:

```
"This is a test one.  This is a test two.  This is a test three."
```

I was hoping to see:

- This is a test one.   This is a test two.     This is a test three.

You can see the regular expression working here at Regex 101:  [Working Regular Expression](http://regex101.com/r/wU0oW9/1)

but instead I'm getting:

```
This is a test one. This is a test two. This is a test three.       $2$2$2      $3$3$3
```

(Where the first cell contains the whole target string and the next two columns contain $2$2$2 and $3$3$3, respectively.)

It look as though (1) the regular expression is not working and (2) that $2 and $3 represent the 2nd and third capture groups, not the 2nd and 3rd instance of the first capture group. Can anyone shed any light on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I misundertood (2). If not: No matter, how often you reference the same match - you do always use the same (well) reference. (How else would you access the other matches?)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry my vba knowledge is limited, but you can do something along the line of the following

```
i = 1
set MyMatches = regEx.test(strInput)
for each match in MyMatches
    c.Offset(0, i) = match
    i++
next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You led me to investigate the Match Object.  It's a collection of matches and you can reference each value using the for each as you indicated along with the value modifier. For example Match.value.

Answer (score 0):

You access matches using the Match Object as alpha bravo indicated in his answer.  The can only create a valid match object by using the Execute method of the RexEx object. Execute was missing from my original code.    In the code below, I have replaced text with Execute and have also used the .Value method to access the values in the Match object.

```
            Set MyMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            match_count = 0
            For Each Match In MyMatches
                match_count = match_count + 1
                c.Offset(0, match_count) = Match.Value
            Next
```

Hope this helps.